# be careful parts of your document may include personal information that cannot be removed by the Document Inspector

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2013, powerpivot

I use `Excel 2013` and `Power View` and `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

After create my `Data Source` and my `chart` in `Excel` When I want save my Excel file I get this message

```
be careful parts of your document may include personal information 
that cannot be removed by the Document Inspector.
```

What is this warning and how I can remove this message?
What are `personal information` that exist in my `Excel File`.

[image]

Comment: Though at this date (2016/02/08) it's not the top answer, I would recommend giving the answer by n1000 a try. IMO it is the best answer.

Comment: Why did you reject both my edits to your [Q](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15059536) and [A](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15059551)? Code formatting is inappropriate and the posts need copy editing

Comment: Just some additional info from my testing with this same issue:  I couldn't get the error to go away on an .xlsm file.  Saved it as an .xlsx and the error went away.  Re-saved it as an .xlsm and no error.  As soon as I added a single line of code, I got the error again.  The line of code was:  'nothing.  Like... commented out code.  Grr.  Sharing the file with my team now gives them a privacy error, which freaks people out.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I fix it with this way :

According to [This](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/be-careful-parts-of-your-document-may-include/fae98705-d078-4fc5-843a-908dda5be559) biography , It says :

I had the same problem, it's incredibly annoying and there's strangely little posted about it on the interwebs. Anyway, here's how you fix it:

- Goto File in the upper left hand corner
- Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Privacy Options >
- Un-check the check box that says "Remove personal information from file properties on save"
- Hit OK.

[image]

Comment: This is a get around rather than a fix as it potentially means you could send a file out with personal info attached. Unfortunately as  MS don't tell us for sure if it is included or what it might be this is often the only option (if the file is for your own personal use only, then this is never an issue)

Comment: This option was grayed-out for me if I ran the Inspector without checking privacy settings. Re-setting this option and unchecking the above (now-enabled) box hasn't fixed the problem inside a VBA project.

Comment: Still nobody has answered how to determine WHICH personal information is in the file.  Why would there be any at all if I don't put it in there?  Does Excel collect my personal information and somehow transmit it to Microsoft so that Bill Gates can mine my work or harvest and sell data about my behavior?

Answer (score 101):

Also ran into that. It seem, after running the [Document Inspector](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-from-office-documents-HA010037593.aspx#BM3) in Excel, it will show you this warning whenever you save your file. 
Go to `File > Info` and click in `"Allow this information to be saved in your file"`. The next time you save there should be no more warning.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend this being the answer as you want excel to remove personal information.

Comment: That's a pretty broad assumption.

Comment: What if I want to know WHICH personal information is in my document, so that I can decide what to do? I mean, it must be referring to individual cells, properties or some other specific data, and I'd like to check this data on my own. Isn't there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by unchecking all options in Privacy Options in Trust Center:
File > Options > Trust Center > Privacy Options